# Generics with static methods

Tags: java, generics

How this works without any Exceptoin ? Because T must be same in this case but one is `String` and another one is `ArrayList<Integer>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<Integer>());   
    System.out.println("s:"+s);
}
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) {
    return a2;
}
```

Comment: If `T` is `Serializable`, then everything fits - String and ArrayList are serializable, so is your result

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers and Replys.It was useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler uses type inference to determine the type of `T`.  It picks the most specific type that works for all types considered.  Here, the type of `s` is `Serializable`, and you pass in a `String` and an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  Both [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are `Serializable`, with no other relation, so the inferred type for `T` is `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you return an object of type T and you store it into a variable of type Serializable, I guess that the compiler infers that T is Serializable in your call, so both String and ArrayList are eligible to be parameters of pick.